Adding DOI automatically to BibTex reference file
I have a file named ref.bib (txt file) that contains a list of articles in BibTeX format. For example, here is one article:
@article{campbell2020beyond,
  title={Beyond zero trust: Trust is a vulnerability},
  author={Campbell, Mark},
  journal={Computer},
  volume={53},
  number={10},
  pages={110--113},
  year={2020},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

I would like to add the DOI to each of the articles in the file by searching the web.
Sometimes, the DOI is related to the name of the article only or can even be found in the citation of the article by another article. Therefore, the scraper should also provide a result in these cases.
The output for the above example would be (ref.bib):
@article{campbell2020beyond,
  title={Beyond zero trust: Trust is a vulnerability},
  author={Campbell, Mark},
  journal={Computer},
  volume={53},
  number={10},
  pages={110--113},
  year={2020},
  publisher={IEEE},
  DOI = {10.1109/MC.2020.3011081}
} 

How can this be done in Python? Is there a way to change the following code to search / scrap the web better?
import requests
import bibtexparser
from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
import sys

def search_doi(title, author):
    """Search for the DOI using the CrossRef API."""
    query = f"{title} {author}"
    url = f"https://api.crossref.org/works?query={query}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        items = data['message']['items']
        if items:
            return items[0]['DOI']  # Return the first DOI found
    return None

def add_doi_to_bibtex(bibtex_file):
    """Add DOI to each entry in the BibTeX file."""
    with open(bibtex_file) as f:
        bibliography = bibtexparser.load(f)

    for entry in bibliography.entries:
        if 'doi' not in entry or entry['doi'].isspace():
            title = entry.get('title', '')
            author = entry.get('author', '')
            doi = search_doi(title, author)
            if doi:
                entry['doi'] = doi
                print(f"Added DOI {doi} to entry: {title}")

    # Write the updated bibliography to a new file
    writer = BibTexWriter()
    with open(bibtex_file.replace('.bib', '_updated.bib'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(writer.write(bibliography))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python add_doi.py <path_to_bibtex_file>")
    else:
        add_doi_to_bibtex(sys.argv[1])


your example already has a doi. and what do you mean by scraping the web "better"?

you have removed the doi but have not answered my question: what do you mean by scraping the web "better"? is your code is working?

@folengateis, It means that I would like to thoroughly scrape the web. Sometimes, the DOI is related to the name of the article only or can even be found in the citation of the article by another article. Therefore, the scraper should also provide a result in these cases.

so this is your real question. and most of your actual question is not related. please [edit] your question to reflect this and provide some example links of pages you can't scrape
